# Magento 2 get product name in summary js file / configuration product name get undefined - attribute

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product, product-attribute, configuration

I need to get a parent product name in vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/adminhtml/web/js/variations/steps/summary.js (summary.js file)
Is it possible if yes how can I achieve this?

for edit configuration product parent proudct name get undefined - attribute
[image]